# What is the default range of Ephemeral Ports in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, port, tcpip, sockets

I used the following command to get the Ephemeral Ports range in Windows 7:

```
netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp
```

And the result was the following:

```
Protocol tcp Dynamic Port Range
---------------------------------
Start Port      : 1025
Number of Ports : 13976
```

Is this is the real default range of Ephemeral Ports in Windows 7, or has the default range been changed somehow (maybe by a software installed on my system)? because I have read that starting from Windows Vista the new default start port is 49152:

> To comply with Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA)
>   recommendations, Microsoft has increased the dynamic client port range
>   for outgoing connections in Windows Vista and in Windows Server 2008.
>   The new default start port is 49152, and the default end port is
>   65535. This is a change from the configuration of earlier versions of Windows that used a default port range of 1025 through 5000.

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit: https://i.imgur.com/PVEujHV.png. I get the expected results.

Comment: @DavidPostill I know it should be 49152 but I also have a windows 7  machine with 1025. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40975904/teamviewer-conflicted-with-jndi-use-higher-port-numbers-for-outgoing-win7

Comment: I can reproduce it on Windows 8.1. Start Port : 1025 Number of ports : 64510. Must be modified by software or service pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it’s not. I tried on multiple VMs with Windows 7, 8.1 and 10, the result is always the same:

```
Protocol tcp Dynamic Port Range
---------------------------------
Start Port      : 49152
Number of Ports : 16384
```

Comment: The command `netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp` on Windows 10 (10.0.19044 Build 19044) showed: `1024 - start, 64511 - number of ports`.
Related: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/default-dynamic-port-range-tcpip-chang